# SQL server 2012: failed to change Database owner

Tags: sql, sql-server

The original owner of the Database has left the company, so I want to change the owner to myself, however, it failed.
When I tried through SSMS: Database properties->Files->Owner, it give the error message like:

> Set owner failed for Database XYZ.
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)

And when I tried through script with the query:

> ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::XYZ TO [MyUserName]

The query seems blocked and run forever without success.
Can anybody give some help?

Answer (score 1):

Queries using dbo-owned objects will acquire a schema stability lock on the existing database owner principal.  The ALTER AUTHORIZATION will need a schema modification lock on the same principal, and are thus blocked due to the incompatible lock.  You can query sys.dm_tran_locks to identify the blocking sessions.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your response, can you elaborate more details about how to diagnostic the problem? the query returns many rows...

Comment: A quick way to identify blocking sessions in general is with sp_who2 or the Activity Monitor in SSMS.  You may have difficulty changing the owner outside a maintenance window if this is an active database.